# React not updating the value of likes and dislikes unless I refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a like and dislike system to a blog I am creating. However, when clicking 'like' for example, the number of likes does not increase and I have to refresh the page to see the new value. I am using the same method for updating the amount of comments and this seems to update fine. The setState functions are apart of my dependency array in the useEffect. I tried to set the actual length as a useState property (not in the code below) and this didn't work either. What am I doing wrong ?

**Setting the likes and dislikes array (of objects) from firebase to a hook in useEffect**

```
useEffect(():any => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    const db = fb.firestore();
    const ref = db.doc(`posts/${props.match.params.id}`)

    ref.get().then((doc: any) => {
      if(doc.exists && isMounted.current) {
    ref.get().then((doc: any) => {
      if(doc.exists && isMounted.current) {
      let store = doc.data()
      setPostData(store);
      setExistingComments(store.comments ? store.comments.reverse() : [])
      setLikes(store['likes'] ? store['likes']  : []);
      setDislikes(store['dislikes'] ? store['dislikes'] : []);

      ... other stuff
}, [setPostData, setExistingComments, props.match.params.id, setLikes, setDislikes, setUserHasDisliked, setUserHasLiked]);
```

**JSX which should display the current length of the likes and dislikes array**

```
<img 
   onClick={()=> onReactionClick("likes")} 
   src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/like.svg'} 
   className={userHasLiked ? 'liked' : ''}
/>
<span>{likes.length}</span>
<img 
   onClick={()=> onReactionClick("dislikes")} 
   src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/like.svg'}
   className={userHasDisliked ? 'disliked' : ''} 
/>
<span>{dislikes.length}</span>
```

**On click function which add the new reaction object to array in firebase**

```
const onReactionClick = (type: string) => {
    if(type === "likes") {
      setUserHasLiked(true)
      setUserHasDisliked(false)
    } else {
      setUserHasDisliked(true)
      setUserHasLiked(false)
    }
    if((type === "likes" && !userHasLiked) || type === "dislikes" && !userHasDisliked) {
      addReaction(type, postData.content.id, fb.auth().currentUser?.displayName, fb.auth().currentUser?.uid, fb.auth().currentUser?.photoURL)
    } 
  }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: check if you store['dislikes'] is an array and not an object (most of the time firebase store everything as an object)

Comment: @phoenixstudio When checking the like and dislike field in Firebase when hovering it has in brackets '(array)'. That's what I want right ?

Comment: Yes array is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to make it work but I'm unsure of how clean it is.

In the `onReactionClick()` function which calls the `addReaction()` function. I have returned the new obj from that function and used `likes.push()` with the returned object to trigger a state update like so:

```
const newReaction = addReaction(type, postData.content.id, fb.auth().currentUser?.displayName!, fb.auth().currentUser?.uid!, fb.auth().currentUser?.photoURL!)
if(type === "likes") {
  likes.push(newReaction)
  } else {
  dislikes.push(newReaction)
}
```

As the `addReaction()` function basically does this logic already except sends it to firebase it probably isn't the right solution but would love to hear of any better ways people find.